# Control does not support transparent background colors. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, transparency

I've written the following to load the backcolor from an ini file:

```
Form1.elect1Label.BackColor = decipherColor(ReadIni.ReadIni("save.ini", "Default", "bg"))
End Sub

Function decipherColor(ByVal undecipheredColor As String) As Color
    Dim deciphered As String = undecipheredColor.Split(New Char() {"[", "]"})(1)
    decipherColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(deciphered)
    Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.Color.FromName(deciphered))
End Function
```

Note that `ReadIni.ReadIni("save.ini', "Default", "bg")` = `Color [A=255 R=255 G=255 B=254]`. The decipherColor function is used to convert colors of the form `Color [RED]` to something that a control will recognise, so instead of doing `control.backcolor = Color.red`, I can do `control.backcolor = decipherColor("Color [RED]")`.

This function works fine, and `Form1.elect1Label.BackColor` becomes `255,255,255,254` (which is form1's transparencyKey) but it will only do this under Windows 7. When running the code under Windows 10, I receive

> Control does not support transparent background colors.

I have found this as a solution: `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);`, however `.SetStyle` is not an available option for `Form1.elect1Label`. This makes me think that `.SetStyle` is `c++` code, not `vb.net`.

Can anyone help me resolve this error under Windows 10?

Comment: `SetStyle()` is not C++ code, however it is only available from within the label itself. Outside code cannot access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it in the end by the following:

```
...
Try 'botch to fix issue #2
    Form1.elect1Label.BackColor = decipherColor(ReadIni.ReadIni("save.ini", "Default", "bg"))
    Form1.elect2Label.BackColor = decipherColor(ReadIni.ReadIni("save.ini", "Default", "bg"))
    Form1.BackColor = decipherColor(ReadIni.ReadIni("save.ini", "Default", "bg"))
Catch ex As Exception
    Form1.elect1Label.BackColor = fixARGB(ReadIni.ReadIni("save.ini", "Default", "bg"))
    Form1.elect2Label.BackColor = fixARGB(ReadIni.ReadIni("save.ini", "Default", "bg"))
    Form1.BackColor = fixARGB(ReadIni.ReadIni("save.ini", "Default", "bg"))
End Try

End Function

Function fixARGB(ByVal brokenARGB As String) As Color
    Dim halfwayThere As String = brokenARGB.Split(New Char() {"[", "]"})(1)
    Dim noA As String = Replace(halfwayThere, "A=", "")
    Dim noR As String = Replace(noA, "R=", "")
    Dim noG As String = Replace(noR, "G=", "")
    Dim clean As String = Replace(noG, "B=", "")
    Dim sept As String() = clean.Split(New Char() {","c})
    fixARGB = Color.FromArgb(sept(0), sept(1), sept(2), sept(3))
End Function
```